# How to export email from the Mail app on iPhone

Tags: iphone, email

I’m trying to save some email. I have 30 days of email living in the Mail app on my iPhone XR running latest ios. I need to export it to .mbox. (Then I’ll try to convert it to .pst to import into outlook but will cross that bridge when I come to it.) Is exporting Mail from iPhone possible? I’ve asked lots of support engineers who’ve washed their hands of this question. Here’s hoping! Thanks in advance. Jan

Comment: What is the backing store for the email?  It's probably much easier to get it from there than from the client.

Comment: Unfortunately it’s on a Rackspace exchange server that’s down from a hacker attack. The mail on my phone is almost the only thing left of 15 years of data.

Comment: Perhaps you can add another IMAP account to the phone, then move the mail from the existing account to that one.

Comment: Does an IMAP account mean perhaps a gmail account? I could do that. But don’t know how to move it from phone to gmail. Have experimented with options on the phone but don’t see the right one. Any thoughts? Many thanks.

Comment: Back the phone up before you do anything else.

Comment: Well, for future reference, I had a tech problem with my iPad and took it in. While I was in the apple store I asked about this issue. Answer is no can do. C’est la vie. Thanks all.